# Проблема Debug assertation failed

Tags: c++

Есть простой алгоритм который должен находить произведение всех чётных цифр 64 разрядного числа, которое может быть отрицательным. При отрицательном числе находит без ошибок и правильно, но если писать положительное то выскакивает следующая ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main() {
   
    string n, o;
    int b;
    short G=0, numcount;
    long long multiplication = 1;
    cin >> n;
    o = n;
    if (o.erase(1, o.length()) == "-") G=1;
    numcount = n.length();
    while (numcount-G >= 0)
    {
        b = n[n.length() - 1];
        b = b + 2;
        b = b % 10; // b - последняя цифра строки
       
       n.erase(n.length()-1, 1);
        if (b % 2 == 0 and b != 0) multiplication *= b;
        numcount = n.length();
    }
    cout << multiplication;
    }
```

P.s: Не нужно предлогать решить с long long, сайт не полностью будет засчитывать решение, хоть всё правильно, наверное это из-за того, что если число негативное, то минус занимает место в памяти, что не даёт полностью записать само число.

Comment: Ну а что вам в этой ошибке не понятно?

Comment: Как ёё исправить чтобы всё работало и считало как нужно

Answer (score 0):

у вас ошибка вот здесь:

```
while (numcount-G >= 0)
```

что приводит к тому, что цикл выполняется когда уже массив/строка `n` не содержит элементов, однако вы всё равно пытаетесь обратиться к элементу `-1`, поскольку `n.length()` уже нулевой

Вообще если ваша задача - найти произведение цифр числа, то вы заметно усложнили свой код и сделали его сильно избыточным

можно же сделать было например так:

```
for (int index = (n[0] == '-' ? 1 : 0); index < n.length(); index++) {
    const int digit = n[index] - 48;

    multiplication *= digit;
}
```

или так:

```
for (const char letter: n) {
    if ((letter >= '0') && (letter <= '9'))
        multiplication *= letter - 48;
}
```

или если считывать не строку, а число (правда тогда есть ограничение на кол-во цифр), то так:

```
n = abs(n);

while (n > 0) {
    multiplication *= n % 10;
    n /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

не работает ничего, что через строку

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   

    string n, o;
    int b;
    short G = 0, numcount;
    unsigned long long multiplication = 1;
    cin >> n;
    o = n;
    if (o.erase(1, o.length()) == "-") G = 1;
    numcount = n.length();
    while (numcount - G > 0)
    {
        b = n[n.length() - 1];
        b = b + 2;
        b = b % 10; // b - останній елемент строки

        n.erase(n.length() - 1, 1);
        if (b % 2 == 0 and b != 0) multiplication *= b;
        numcount = n.length();
    }
    if (multiplication != 1) cout << multiplication;
    else cout << "-1";
    
    





 
       
    
}
```

и через челочисленные операции не работает, не проходит 2 теста здесь https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/1604